# How do I use jquery inside WordPress Loop?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, loops, effect

How do I use jquery inside WordPress Loop without repeating effect

```
<div class="post">
       <?php if ( have_posts() ) : 
       while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
           <a class="post_image"  href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" >
               <img  class="post_image_home"  src='<?php $thumb = get_post_custom_values('post_thumb'); echo $thumb[0]?>'   alt="postimg" />
           </a><!--post_image-->
       <?php endwhile; endif; ?></div><!--post-->
```

jquery :

```
    $j=jQuery.noConflict();
   $j('document').ready(function() {
      $j('.post').hover(function() {
             $j('.post_image').stop().animate({"margin-bottom":"10px",},"fast");
             },function(){
             $j('.post_image').stop().animate({"margin-bottom":"0px",},"fast");
      });            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not add this to a JS file? Would probably be better than having JS inside a PHP file, and that would prevent it from running each time PHP goes through the loop.

If you must do it within the PHP file, you could create a global JS variable before your loop starts, and just check that before running your own JS/jQuery stuff. Inside the JS in the loop, change that global variable so it won't run again.

**== EDIT ==**

Here's some example code for including a separate JS file with your theme.

This would be in your functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'front_end_js_files');
function front_end_js_files(){
    // shouldn't be needed, but to be safe
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    // this is looking in the same dir as your functions.php
    wp_enqueue_script('my_own_file', get_bloginfo('template_url') . 'my_own_file.js');
}
```

And then in my_own_file.js, paste your jQuery. Just note that your JS will now be included on every page, so you may want to make the jQuery selector a bit more specific. Or, add some custom page detection in PHP before you enqueue the script.

Comment: i Need an example I beginner XD pls